# format a number with dots and decimals in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need first .(dot) then comma(,).

like, 1234567 this is an example number or money
I want it like 1.234.567,00
can anybody give me an answer.

Comment: How are you calling the change, in a `.ToString()` or in a `String.Format(` or similar call?

Comment: A better solution to this is change the culture of your pc.

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal(Amount).ToString("#.##0,00");

Comment: On the principle of "teach a man to fish", search the MSDN for "double tostring format" and you'll find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - then you need to choose your format (to be specific) or format provider (to choose e.g. a particular regional culture).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a foreign currency format.  There may be multiple ways of doing this based on what you really want.  The following MSDN link give you the full documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString

an example that works is the following:

```
        string xyz = "1234567";

        // Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;

        nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
        nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
        nfi.CurrencySymbol = "";
        var answer = Convert.ToDecimal(xyz).ToString("C3", 
              nfi);
```

xyz = 1.234.567,000

Answer (score 11):

If the culture settings on the computer where the code is executed correspond with your wishes, you can simply use a ToString overload as:

```
    double d = 1234567;
    string res = d.ToString("#,##0.00");  //in the formatting, the comma always represents the group separator and the dot the decimal separator. The format part is culture independant and is replaced with the culture dependant values in runtime.
```

if the display has to be culture independent, you can use a specific numberformatinfo:

```
 var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", NumberGroupSeparator = "." };
    double d = 1234567;
    string res = d.ToString("#,##0.00", nfi); //result will always be 1.234.567,00
```

Comment: Sorry I want Dot then Comma like 1.234.567,00    @Me.Name

Comment: For the formatting in code, the comma always represents the group seperator, and not the character actually displayed. The 2nd code above will always display 1.234.567,00 . The first code too, if the culture settings correspond as such

Answer (score 1):

You can change the culture of the application on the fly as well. If you take a look at [Formatting Numeric Data for a Specific Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and look at the section labeled "Formatting Currency for Euro Nations", it will explain in detail how to do this.

Basically, you'll want to change the culture using:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

And then you can use the .ToString() method, passing "c" as a parameter, indicating you want the string formatted as a currency for the current culture:

```
double d = 1234567;
string converted = d.ToString("c");
```

That should give you what you're looking for. Just make sure to set the culture back, if you don't want European style numbers for everything you're working with.